# How can I see multiple Bluetooth entries that correspond to a single device?

Tags: gnome, audio, manjaro, bluetooth

I'm on Manjaro 20.1 (Mikah), using Gnome 3.36, and I'm struggling to smoothly pair my laptop with the Sony WF-1000XM3 (using the latest firmware, 2.3.0).

When pairing, the earbuds normally appear as two devices (in Windows, for example): LE_WF-1000XM3 and WF-1000XM3. The first one is to connect to the iOS/Android application (change adv settings), while the latter is the actual sound device (that is, if you connect to the first one, the OS doesn't detect it as a sound device). The problem is that in the Gnome Bluetooth panel, there is only one entry for the device (LE_WF-1000XM3) that periodically toggles for a second or so to WF-1000XM3. In other words, the bluetooth manager somehow 'knows' that it's actually one device and doesn't list them separately.

At the moment, I lucked out and got them working by playing whac-a-mole and clicking on the device when it briefly switched to WF-1000XM3, but I'm hoping for a long-term solution: somehow listing the two devices independently and connecting to the correct one.

Edit:

"WF-1000XM3" represents Bluetooth Classic connection, and "LE_WF-1000XM3" represents Bluetooth Low Energy connection. Classic is used for streaming Audio, and LE is used for communicating with the app and displaying the battery status." - From [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sony/comments/g8xdax/difference_in_bluetooth_connection_between/) thread.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm only having the LE device show up (which disappears if I click to pair), so I can't connect to the earphones...

Comment: @ljden: Kind of—get AirPods Pro. I know, it sucks, but I'll save you the time—I bought 4 (yes, 4) different earbuds (Sony, Samsung, Jabra, and TaoTronics) and all of them had this problem. Then I borrowed my wife's Airpods Pro—worked right away, no LE_ shenanigans. Not sure what witchcraft Apple pulled off, but the difference was heaven and earth. I also noticed this wasn't an issue with a TaoTronics headset (rather than earbuds), so if that's an option for you, could be cheaper.

Comment: And I'm not a linux expert by any means, but I'm running the latest version of my distro (incl. latest firmware), which as I understand it tends to have best hardware support.

Comment: Cheers, I did a little more digging and it looks like a firmware issue on either the earphones side or BT chip (I'm guessing earphones here but it's purely conjecture).  I've connected my headphones with my laptop no problems, will just have to use the earphones with my phone instead